# select and where condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In this coding iam checking the whether email id is present in database.After that i need to change password.

```
function user_password($input, $serviceName){
        $ipJson = json_encode($input);
        $updateArray = array(
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => md5($input['password']),
            'user_modified_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        );
        $this->db->where('email', $input['email']);
        $update = $this->db->update('users', $updateArray);
        if ($update) {
            $data['message'] = 'email id is present';
            $status = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('success', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
        } 
        else {
            $data['message'] = 'Error In Updating Please Check Your Email ID';
            $status = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('error', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
        }
        return $status;
    }
```

if email is present in db i need to get "email id is present" message else i need to get "error"message.how i need to check the condition.

Comment: I think you want to update on the bases on email? If record is updated than you want to print that "email is present"?

Comment: before updating i need to check

Comment: instead of if($update) what i need to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to check that email address already in use or not. 
So in model

```
$this->db->where("email",$input['email']);
$query = $this->db->get("users");
if($query->num_rows()>0){
   $status['message'] = 'Email Already Exist';
}
```

Comment: instead of if($upadate) line i need to write if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0)  this line

Comment: you will use that in case when you want to check if any row is affected by you query.

Comment: now the if body will check that email is present or not. if it is present you can return from there and display message that email exist. write the update code in the else part.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function user_password($input, $serviceName)
    {
         $ipJson = json_encode($input);
         $updateArray = array(
           'email' => $input['email'],
           'password' => md5($input['password']),
           'user_modified_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
         );
         $this->db->where('email', $input['email']);
         $update = $this->db->update('users', $updateArray);
        if ($update==TRUE) 
        {
           $data['message'] = 'email id is present';
           $status = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('success', $serviceName, $data,    $ipJson);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $data['message'] = 'Error In Updating Please Check Your Email ID';
            $status = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('error', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
        }
        return $status;
    }
```

//change your update function in model something like this:

```
function update('users',$updatearray)
{
    if(is_array($dataarray))
    {
       $this->db->trans_start();
       $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email'));
       $this->db->update('table',$updatearray);
       $this->db->trans_complete();
       return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
       return FALSE
    }

}
```